# Get date for every year july using NSDate 

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

How to get date for every year of july month using NSDate .I am getting the data from the web service which I called. And now I am showing the full data in the graph which is very huge. The data which we are having is from 1998 to till now. so I want to show the data only every year of july. For this I need the help. Can anyone help me?

Comment: can you explain more on the same and also the ways you have tried to implement?

Comment: This is very hard to understand. What's the connection between a Core Plot graph and a date?

Comment: i am getting the data from the web service which i call. And now i am showing the full data in the graph which is very huge. the data which we are having is from 1998 to till now. so i want to show the data only every year of july. For this i need the help.

Comment: Please add what you said in comment into your question by editing it.

Comment: I think you question is like you want to show only july month of data for every year?

Comment: yes. what you said is right. For that what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Well, NSDate is a specific date and time and not just month and year. If you're fine with something like every July 1 at 12 AM (or whatever time/day) then you can use NSDateComponents to set the components of the date.

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setMonth:5];
[comps setYear:2004];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
    initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
[comps release];
[gregorian release];
```

This is straight from the Apple documentation. If you want to get the next year, then you can use `dateByAddingTimeInterval:` on your NSDate to return a new date (or you can use the original NSDateComponents and `setYear:` in a loop).